# Match sentences containing a given word

Tags: sqlite

I have a sentence column in my table. I wish to select all sentences which contain a given word.

Words contain only the following letters: a-z, áéíóú

The only other character is a single space, separating each word in the sentence. There are no spaces at the start or end of a sentence. So sentences look like this:

```
"i am here"
"no im here"
```

selecting sentences containing the word "i" should only match the first sentence above.

How should I select these rows from my table?

Comment: Wildcards my friend! http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp

Off the top of my head, sentences containing the word i could be %i %, sentences starting with i could be, i %.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based upon the information you have provided there are three permutations you need to cover.

- The word you are searching for is the first word in the sentence. In this case there will be no space before the word but there will be a space after the word.
- The word you are searching for is not the first word nor the last word in the sentence. In this case there will be a space either side of the word.
- The word you are searching for is the last word in the sentence. In this case there will be a space before the word but none after the word.

So your query would look something like this ...

```
SELECT * FROM YourTableName 
    WHERE SentenceCol LIKE 'YOUR-SEARCH-WORD %' 
    OR SentenceCol LIKE '% YOUR-SEARCH-WORD %' 
    OR SentenceCol LIKE '% YOUR-SEARCH-WORD'
```